# Qt C++ - multithread video frame transformation

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, user-interface

I have to write an app that displays a loaded video in one Widget, pulls frames, transforms them, and puts these in another Widget, preferably QGraphicsView, and hopefully synchronized. It's pretty important for them to be synchronized.

I've written a test thread, and the main meat is this:

```
void HSV::display() {
Ui::MainWindow ui; //1
int j=0;
QTimer *timer = new QTimer;
for(int i=1; i<4; i++){
    QString numer = QString::number(i);
    QImage imageTest(numer+".jpg");
    QGraphicsPixmapItem* test = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap::fromImage(imageTest));
    QGraphicsScene* sceneHSV = new QGraphicsScene;
    sceneHSV->addItem(test);
    //2
    ui.graphicsViewKalibracjaHSV->setScene(sceneHSV);
    ui.graphicsViewKalibracjaHSV->fitInView(sceneHSV->sceneRect(),Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
    ui.graphicsViewKalibracjaHSV->show();
    timer->start(500);
    if(i==3) {
        i=1;
    }
    j++;
    if (j>40) {
        break;
    }
    }
}
```

it's not what I need, but it's just a test. If I put text there, it goes through just fine, keeps displaying. But these images... immediatly a crash when the first ui line is reached ( //2 ). I have no doubt this way of doing things is really bad.

If I remove `Ui::MainWindow ui;` at //1 , it tells me that `ui is not declared in this scope` .

So my question is, how can I access and modify ui elements in the Mainwindow from a separate thread?

edit: 
Okay, a more practical idea. I'm going to simply pass video file URL from the GUI thread to the worker thread, do all the operations there and pass 2 processed images back (for each video frame), one for each QGraphicsView. One normal, with points marked, and one transformed. I now know how to pass things from worker thread to GUI thread, but how do I pass QString from GUI to the worker thread, and how do I receive it?

Comment: I see no **ui->setupUi(this);**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you can't.

Qt Help: Threading Basics:

> GUI Thread and Worker Thread
>
> As mentioned, each program has one thread when it is started. This
>   thread is called the "main thread" (also known as the "GUI thread" in
>   Qt applications). The Qt GUI must run in this thread. All widgets and
>   several related classes, for example QPixmap, don't work in secondary
>   threads. A secondary thread is commonly referred to as a "worker
>   thread" because it is used to offload processing work from the main
>   thread.

What you can do: you can work with ui in main thread, pass `QImage` (or other data, not related with ui) into separate thread through signal/slot system, process it there and pass it back.

**UPDATE** (*how can I do that? I mean, pass QImage back and forth between threads and display both videos simultaneously and continually? –  Petersaber*)

I'm not a video expert, but I can give you I hint. Let's assume, you have a `Widget`, which accepts `QImage` and have to show it. `Processor` is an object, which processes an image and returns it back to gui thread. `Processor` should be derived from `QObject`.

**Widget.h**

```
class Widget : public QWidget, private Ui::Widget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void enqueueImage(const QImage &img);

signals:
    void process(const QImage &img);

private:
    void showNextImage();

private slots:
    void onProcessed(const QImage &img);

private:
    QThread *mThread;
    QScopedPointer < Processor > mProcessor;
    QList < QImage > mImagesPool;
};
```

**Widget.cpp**

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
  , mThread(new QThread(this))
  , mProcessor(new Processor)
{
    setupUi(this);
    mProcessor->moveToThread(mThread);
    connect(this, SIGNAL(process(QImage)), mProcessor, SLOT(process(QImage)));
    connect(mProcessor, SIGNAL(processed(QImage)), SLOT(onProcessed(QImage)));
}

void Widget::enqueueImage(const QImage &img)
{
    mImagesPool.append(img);
    showNextImage();
}

void Widget::showNextImage()
{
    if (mImagesPool.isEmpty())
        return;
    emit process(mImagesPool.first());
}

void Widget::onProcessed(const QImage &img)
{
    if (mImagesPool.isEmpty())
        return;
    rawImage->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(mImagesPool.takeFirst()));
    processedImage->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));
    showNextImage();
}
```

**Processor.cpp**

```
void Processor::process(const QImage &img)
{
    QImage newImg = img;
    // Do stuff
    emit processed(newImg);
}
```

Comment: This is "how can I access and modify ui elements in the Mainwindow from a separate thread?". So why do you say he can't? ;-)

Comment: No, this is how you can process data in separate thread. You can't **actually** access and modify ui elements form other thread, you must do all of this in the main one. May be I'm a bit strict :)

Comment: The gui must run in the main thread. But this has nothing to do with modifying or accessing ui elements. Those are only data, too. Can be accessed the same way as any function/data can be accessed over thread boundaries.

Comment: I disagree. When you read Qt's help for `QImage`, for example, one of the first lines says `Note: All functions in this class are reentrant.` There is no such note for `QWidget`, for example. The same help says: `If a function is not marked as thread-safe or reentrant, it should not be used from different threads. If a class is not marked as thread-safe or reentrant then a specific instance of that class should not be accessed from different threads.` Which means **you should not access ui data from separate threads**.

Comment: Since when must functions be thread-safe to be accessed from another thread?

Comment: I guess, they ment functions, that gain access to data, which is not protected by mutex e.t.c.. For example, a lot of Qt's functions work with singletons and static variables.

Comment: I know, I enjoyed a bit of nitpicking. For instance: When you send a clicked signal from a button to another thread, it is accessing ui data from another thread. The same way, over signal/slots you can change ui data, e.g. show/hide elements, change layouts, change texts. The general: **You should not access ui data from separate threads** is too strong for my taste. You just cannot access ui directly without any form of protection, but this is true for all non-thread-safe functions or data.

Comment: how can I do that? I mean, pass QImage back and forth between threads and display both videos simultaneously and continually?