# How to correctly update an image in a QLabel?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, signals-slots, qpixmap

I am building a GUI in which I need to update an image displayed in a [QLabel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.4/qlabel.html) whenever a certain event happens.

Although showing an initial image in the [QLabel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.4/qlabel.html) on startup works fine, whenever I try to change this image later in the event callback function, `ui_.label->setPixmap(p)` fails & produces this error:

> QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread

I tried to use a signal-slot mechanism too:

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(updatePixmap(const QPixmap&)), ui_.label, SLOT(setPixmap(const QPixmap&)));
```

where `updatePixmap(const QPixmap&)` is a signal I emit in the event callback function (i.e. I replace `ui_.label->setPixmap(p)` by `updatePixmap(p)`)

but still getting the same error...

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you should create `QImage` and send it  to the gui thread and convert using `Qimage::toPixmap()`

Comment: @HienNgo can you detail a bit more? How can I send a QImage to the gui thread? And should I use signal-slot?

Comment: Instead of creating a `QPixmap` in your other thread, create a `QImage` and send that to your GUI thread via a signal/slot connection.

Comment: @Beginner, Yes, you should try !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30077177/qt-c-multithread-video-frame-transformation/30077499